# How would you go about making an online IRB that runs in the browser

Tags: ruby, irb

Im wondering how to go about creating an online IRB that runs in the browser. I have an idea to include an irb console in my blog and give the option for users to send code blocks in my tutorials directly into the irb console so they can play around with it.

_Why did this previously, but of course it is gone now: [Cached Version](http://74.125.95.132/search?q=cache:KPJzhKXWkGsJ:tryruby.hobix.com/+ruby+online+irb&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca&client=firefox-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TryRuby is still available [here](http://tryruby.org/), with [source code at GitHub](http://github.com/Sophrinix/TryRuby/tree/master).

Comment: I forked that repository and setup it local but it is not working. It is in some different language and code is also last updated almost 4 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could use the sandbox that [_why created](http://github.com/whymirror/sandbox/tree/master). But you'll need to be able to patch your ruby and it seems to only work on ruby 1.8.5 .

Comment: It apparently has security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

That's insanely dangerous. Don't do this. You expose your system to all sorts of vulnerabilities when you allow users to execute arbitrary Ruby code.

Anyway there are some client-side Ruby implementations in JavaScript/Flash. Take a look at [HotRuby](http://hotruby.yukoba.jp/).

Comment: Dude, calm down. I don't think he's planning to run his online IRB unsandboxed on his accounting records server.

Comment: Even a sandboxed IRB on your server is questionable to me. If you're going to implement this, you need to really stay on top of security updates and things like that.

Comment: This is much less risk than your average Web host takes on, and nobody says, "OMG, don't host Web sites! You'll expose your system to all sorts of vulnerabilities!"

Comment: Apparently _why's script was found to have security vulnerabilities.

Comment: What? It gives out your social security number?

Comment: If you think data access is the only concern with security, you've got a lot to learn...

Comment: Additionally, if he has to ask about this, I doubt he knows well enough how to sandbox and protect his server for securely running untrusted code.

Comment: Again, is it more dangerous than allowing people to host dynamic Web sites on your server?

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect you run Ruby in a sandbox to prevent "bad" commands being run.